# How to calculate the normal vector?

Tags: c++, reflection, sfml, trigonometry

I'm making a game with lasers. I need to reflect the lasers against a rotated object, but I can't find the correct normal vector.

Example:

- Point A (0, 20) goes to point B (15, 5).
- My velocity is (1, -1) * Speed.
- A wall from point C (15, 0) to point D (15, 50).
- Wall standing upright.

Now I need to calculate the normal and normalize it (I know how to normalize). The normalize vector should be (-1, -1), but how do I calculate this? Do I need to use dotproduct, the angle or something else?

Comment: Seems more like a question for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will ask it on math.stackexhange.com

Comment: He has the normal value, but I don't. I already know the reflection formula. I made the same game with UE4, and know I'm trying to make it without game engine, but the only problem is that I don't know the normal vector.

Comment: There are two normals to any line, so you need a convention to tell you which to take. But to calculate the normal, swap the components of the separation vector and change the sign of *one* of them.

Comment: Give me a minute and I will post an answer

Comment: Do you mean to add minus when the laser goes to right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a wall which goes from point `A` to `B`:

[image]

`C` is at a 90-degree *anti-clockwise* rotation with respect to the direction `AB`, and `D` is clockwise. The components of `C` are given by `[Ay - By, Bx - Ax]`, and those of `D` are simply minus these.

You will need to choose a consistent convention for taking either `C` or `D` as the normal for any wall, which means you will need to be careful with the *ordering* of wall points.

E.g. for `A = [0, 20], B = [15, 5]`, the normal `C = [15, 15]` and `D = [-15, -15]`. The normalized version of `D` is `[-1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2)]` and *not* `[-1, -1]` (are you *sure* you know how to normalize?)

Comment: So if I know the intersection side is left, I just need to add minus before X?

Comment: What is `X`? Anyway you would need to take the `C` vector instead of `D`. Also the term "left" depends on the order of the points; if you take the wall as going from `B` to `A` then the "left" normal would be `D`.

Comment: Normalize:                       float length = std::sqrt(N.x * N.x + N.y * N.y);
     N.x /= length;
     N.y /= length;

Comment: If you knew this formula, then why did you say the normalized answer should be `[-1, -1]`?

Comment: I already knew about normalize, but I didn't knew how to calculate C and D. The velocity of the laser is (1, -1) * Speed. When it hits a upright wall, it reflects and the new velocity should be (-1, -1) * speed. That's what I thought.

Comment: Question: what is the value of `length` for `[-1, -1]`? And what is the *definition* of a normalized vector? Anyways I hope my post has answered your question.

Comment: Normalized vector is a number between 0 and 1, right?

Comment: Firstly, is the length of `[-1, -1]` within this range? Secondly, the length of **any** normalized vector is always **1**.

Comment: I'm getting confused.

Comment: Would you like me to rephrase the question, or are you confused about something else?

Comment: About how you calculated C [15, 15] and D [-15, -15]

Comment: Using the formula I gave? `C = [Ay - By, Bx - Ax]`. Just plug in the numbers.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about the vectors of the wall in my question

Comment: It makes sense now

Comment: Last question: how do I know if I need to use C or D? Just calculate the direction of the laser?

Comment: Please read the last part of my answer... I said that for a general situation that's a decision *you* as the programmer need to make. **However**, for the reflection formula you can in fact use *either* `C` or `D`.

Comment: Thanks man! I think I know how to fix it now. Next week I'm going to improve my math because it has been 2,5 years. I learned a lot about reflection now.

Comment: No problem. A good grasp of vector math is extremely important in any kind of graphics programming

Comment: I know. In the beginning it's hard to go from application developer to game developer (if you havn't had math for some years).

Comment: I got reflection. It isn't done, but I think I can fix it on my own right now. Thanks!!

Comment: I have one question.

Comment: If I use cross product instead of dot product, it works. But that is the wrong method?

Comment: @sanderlemmen hmm, I'm pretty sure `sf::vector2f` has its own normalisation function and basic arithmetic operators. Recommend you to use those to make the code more readable and less error-prone. This should technically be a new question post though...

Comment: I need to clean up my code, but sf has no dotproduct, normalisation functions

Comment: @sanderlemmen found the problem - your `NormalHit` vector is just the  wall span vector and not actual normal. Use the formula in my answer

Comment: Do you mean this: [-1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(2)]? Or what is wrong?

Comment: @sanderlemmen I meant the *formula* for the normal `C = [Ay - By, Bx - Ax]`. Your `NormalHit` variable was `[Bx - Ax, By - Ay]`

Comment: @sanderlemmen see my answer on your new post; you should use `atan2` to handle all 4 quadrants and edge cases correctly. This comment thread is getting too long; please move the conversation to your new post

Answer (score 0):

To normalize a vector you divide the vector by its magnitude...

```
point A: [0, 20] / root[sqr(0) + sqr(20)]= [(0 / 20), (20 / 20)] = [0, 1]
```

Comment: how did you get [-1, -1] from normalized vector point A [0, 20]?

Comment: the vectors velocity in that direction is the magnitude speed has nothing to do with it... what is this laser project you have? can I see it, I too have a laser

Comment: This is what I thought. Maybe I explained it wrong. The start velocity is (1, -1), so the laser goes to right. When it hits a straight wall, it should go to left. So the new velocity should be (-1, -1).

Comment: I was confused about all those math terms

Comment: I think that your approaching this in a more physical way than rational ...you know a normal is of unit length of 1 and cannot take a negative....if I said that [-1, -1] is the correct answer ...would you be happy?

Comment: I understood it differently

Comment: Thats cool Sander, you'll get the hang of it, cheer up...this topic must've helped you

Comment: It helped me a lot. It isn't easy if you haven't had math in 2,5 years. I'm going to improve my math next week...