# How to find a point along a contour path given the distance from a point on the contour?

Tags: java, c++, geometry, distance, points

I have a contour with certain points defined.
I m trying to offset the position of the starting point by a certain distance along the contour like shown below.
Pt A to Pt A'. I have the offset distance as say 0.5 mm.
I already have details of co-ordinates of Pt A.

- How to find the coordinates of A'(along the contour path), given the offset value ( ***This offset is not the linear distance but the distance along the contour***)?
- Additionally how to programmatically achieve this in C++ or JAVA?

[image: Contour Path]

Comment: compute the [normal and vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843048/6651840) of the line between the two points, then use that to add your distance

Comment: How to find the second point ( A' in this case). I only have the distance from A

Comment: you can use [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=96&v=v9-wXYX8gEc&feature=emb_logo)

Comment: Why is this tagged C when you are asking for C++?

Comment: Finding a distance along a curve requires information about the curve, such as a function that describes it. The fact it is a “contour” is insufficient information. You need to add enough information to the question to uniquely identify the curve.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen: That video addresses straight-line Euclidean distance and is not useful for distance along a curve.